# Как спарсить два img src с одной ячейки таблицы?

Tags: phpquery

Здравствуйте дело в том что есть таблица и в третьей её ячейки лежат две картинки когда начинаю парсить переносится только src первой картинки и всё так с любым атрибутом происходит как сделать что бы парсила все src которые находятся в ячейки кстати если не указываю какой атрибут нужен а просто задаю что ищу в ячейки img то всё нормально полностью все картинки с ячейки переносятся на мой сайт но нужно именно атрибут src ну или alt, помогите пожалуйста разобраться.
`

```
require('/phpQuery/phpQuery.php');
define('HOST','royalquest.info/index.php?title=%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BB...'); 

$data_site = file_get_contents(HOST);
$document = phpQuery::newDocument($data_site);
$content_prev = $document->find('tr');

foreach ($content_prev as $el)
{
$pq = pq($el);
$img = $pq->find('td:nth-child(3) img')->attr('src'); 

echo ' картинка: ' . $img . '';
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Пробуйте):

```
    $pq = $content_prev;
$img = $pq->find('td:nth-child(3) img')->attr('src'); 
        foreach ($img as $i) {
            echo ' картинка: ' . $i . '';
        }
```

Comment: Не ничего не происходит)

Comment: Я почитал и вроде здесь надо как то сделать через each перебрать массив через цикл с помощью jQuery each function:

// Массивы
var arr = [
   'один',
   'два',
   'три',
   'четыре',
   'пять'
];
$.each(arr, function (index, value) {
  console.log(value);
  
  // Выполнение останавливается после "три"
  return (value !== 'три');
});
// Результат: один два три